# while removing skype to install skype on ubuntu 14.04 I have all my files deleted

Tags: files, skype

Please help me...
I never use rm command but stupidly I did use this one below and as a result have all my files deleted including chrome bookmarks and settings.I lost a huge amount of my scientific data too.
How do i recover them?

sudo apt-get remove skype skype-bin

rm -rf ~/ .skype

Comment: If you had space between ~/ and .skype, you told it to remove `~/`, and `~` is symbol for home folder. That is why you always should add `-i` before `rm` command.

Comment: Stop using the computer or it could overwrite the deleted files.  Boot only from a live CD and use recovery tools (such as `testdisk` & `photorec`) to recover lost files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to recover deleted files?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files)

Comment: chrome bookmarks ? haven't you got configured gmail account with chrome?

Comment: Thanks a lot all of you. i don't mind loosing bookmarks but the folders in my home directory were a disaster. and  Serg yes you are right I did have a space and that killed my home directory . Thanks I will use -i (which I think means individual folders i guess..) I am new to Ubuntu but loving it and will keep working on it. I copied and pasted the command from a skype forum  which I am not going to do EVER in the future.